# video is always wrong when using cv::videowriter

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I have written a test code using cv::videowriter, the video is always wrong(undesired color and shape). But the frames were correct when I saved them via cv::imwrite. The system is centos 7, opencv 2.4.5, ffmpeg 2.6.8
thank a lot![sorry, I cannot publish the test result, the output aaaaa.jpg is a gray image, but the video capture is a color image with green and pink]

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include "/usr/include/opencv/cv.h"
#include "/usr/include/opencv/highgui.h"

int main(int, char**)
{
    cv::VideoWriter outputVideo;
    outputVideo.open("out.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30,         cv::Size(400,400), true);
    if (!outputVideo.isOpened()){
        printf("aaa\n");
    }
    cv::Mat frame, f1,f2, f3;
    char *Frame_buff = (char *)(malloc(400 * 400 * 3));
    for(int iii = 0; iii < 400; iii++) {
        for(int jjj = 0; jjj < 400; jjj++) {
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 0] = iii;
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 1] = iii;
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 2] = iii;  
        }
    }

    frame = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8UC3, Frame_buff);
    f1 = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8UC3, Frame_buff);
    cv::imwrite("aaaaa.jpg", f1);

    for(int iii = 0; iii < 400; iii++) {
        for(int jjj = 0; jjj < 400; jjj++) {
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 0] = jjj;
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 1] = jjj;
            Frame_buff[jjj * 400 * 3 + iii * 3 + 2] = jjj;  
       }
    }
    f2 = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    cv::imwrite("bbbb.jpg", f2);
    f3 = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8UC3, Frame_buff);
    cv::imwrite("cccc.jpg", f3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 240; i++){
        if(i < 80){
            printf("ccc");
            outputVideo.write(f1);
        }
        else if(i<160){
            printf("bbb");
            outputVideo.write(frame);
        }
        else{
            printf("aaa");
            outputVideo.write(f2);
        }       
    }
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    outputVideo.release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be more careful while editing. You lost an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my test results, I'm not sure what you're problem is but your description is not consistent with me running your code above:

[image: aaaa.jpg]
[image: bbbb.jpg]
[image]

The output video runs like this:

```
Shows an image like cccc.jpg for 4.5(ish) seconds, Shows bbbb.jpg for 3.5ish seconds
```

Comment: Just like the first and third image，they are all grayscale images.But when I write it to the video[like this code:outputVideo.write(f1)],grayscale change to RGB images(green and pink),that is what puzzles me.So how can I solve this problem,thanks~

Comment: Like I say, for me the output video looks like the saved images, its likely a codec issue for you

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again！I found the video has no problem when it played in centos7, but when I play it in win10,red image become to green,green become to blue, and blue change to red.Do you why does this happen,thank you !